# cannot move Kaggle.json to /root/.kaggle in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am working on Colab.

To get the kaggle training data (https://www.kaggle.com/muerbingsha/pandatiledsingle/settings), I used kaggle API.

- upload kaggle.json to Colab
- move kaggle.json to /root/.kaggle

Theses steps work well in previous days. But today It gave me error of

```
mv: cannot move 'kaggle.json' to '/root/.kaggle/': Not a directory
```

**Error Screenshot** (for better explanation)
[image]
This problem is really weird. How to deal with this, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I found asking on StackOverflow is really a good way to find solutions!!! Yeah, time saving!!!

When I was typing the question, I found that since it says `!mv ... not a directory` and `!ls no such file or directory`, maybe there is no folder of .kaggle.

I tried to create the folder and just follow the instructions if any error happens

```
!pip install kaggle -q      # At first, I suspect the kaggle API lose effect so it doesn't have .kaggle folder. (not working)
!rm -rf /root/.kaggle.      # when I created the folder, it says the file or dir already exits
!mkdir /root/.kaggle        # successful
!mv kaggle.json /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json    # not sure if I have to use full destination path, I previously only used /root/.kaggle and it failed. Don't have time to validate this thought.
!ls /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle datasets download muerbingsha/pandatiledsingle
```

#### Conclusion:

The Colab environment changed that .kaggle is lost for unknown reasons.